# Getting current timestamp in inline pipeline script using pipeline plugin of hudson

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get Getting current timestamp in inline pipeline script using pipeline plugin of hudson. For setting up build display name.

Inline groovy script used:

```
def jobName = env.JOB_NAME + "_" + new Date()
currentBuild.displayName = "$jobName"
node {
   echo "job name $jobName"
}
```

Error on console :

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: 
  Scripts not permitted to use new java.util.Date
```

Comment: Have you once searched for the RejectedAccessException? Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/39412951/6894050

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jenkins scripts are running in a sandbox, by default the *Groovy* script doesn't have permissions for some operations.

When you perform an operation without permissions the `RejectAccessException` is thrown. So you've to execute your script, and then when the exception is thrown go to:

```
http://yourHost/jenkins/scriptApproval/
```

And approve the necessary permission:

[image]

Answer (score 36):

you can also use this, I needed this in ms so:

```
echo "TimeStamp: ${currentBuild.startTimeInMillis}"

echo "TimeStamp: ${Util.getTimeSpanString(System.currentTimeMillis())}"
```

Comment: The first command is working fine for me. Thanks  @Camilo Silva

Answer (score 35):

Just format the `Date` object:

```
stage('Foo') {
  steps {
    script {
        def now = new Date()
        println now.format("yyMMdd.HHmm", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 29):

There are a bunch of ways to get time depending on what APIs you find most intuitive:

1. [`new Date()` has since been added to the `script-security-plugin` whitelist](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/7cdf0bdc4e420ac96390f857fc162a98feee7220/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist#L282-L283)
2. [`RunWrapper`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/d0898011f1f2fd9344f0622f6d21e677b97c12e0/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java) APIs through use of `currentBuild` global variable

   1. [`final long startTime = currentBuild.startTimeInMillis`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getStartTimeInMillis--): `long` value of when the build was started in milliseconds
   2. [`final long scheduledTime = currentBuild.timeInMillis`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getTimeInMillis--): `long` value of when the build was scheduled in milliseconds
   3. [`final long buildDuration = currentBuild.duration`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getDuration--): milliseconds it has taken to build
   4. [`final String buildDurationAsStrong = currentBuild.durationString`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getDurationString--): `duration` as a `String`
3. [Using whitelisted `java.time`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/7cdf0bdc4e420ac96390f857fc162a98feee7220/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist#L122-L227) APIs, for example [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

   ```groovy
   import java.time.LocalDateTime
   final LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
   // do stuff with LocalDateTime
   ```
4. Of course, shelling out and using the return value in your script

   ```groovy
   final String currentTime = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +%Y-%m-%d').trim()
   ```

And I'm sure there are other methods, too.

Comment: In my case, #4 (shelling out) was the go for the time and log tracking tasks as node servers occasionally were out of time sync even for few minutes.

Answer (score 15):

You can also avoid script approvals by using `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate` in string context.  These will give you ISO 8601 defaults:

```
script {
  DATE_TAG = java.time.LocalDate.now()
  DATETIME_TAG = java.time.LocalDateTime.now()
}
sh "echo ${DATETIME_TAG}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short way to print timestamp in your **local timezone**:

```
String.format('%tF %<tH:%<tM', java.time.LocalDateTime.now())
```

I'm using it to [set build name and description](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-name-setter/), with a [groovy token](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/#plugin-content-token-macro-plugin-support), for example:

`${GROOVY,script = "String.format('%tF %<tH:%<tM', java.time.LocalDateTime.now())"}`

Prints my local time: 2021-12-05 16:07

Note that [build.getTimestampString2()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getTimestampString2--) would also print the timestamp, but **in UTC** (might be different than your timezone).