# In Jenkins pipeline, how can I convert a String to Date?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I just want to be able to convert `2019-11-05T08:43:43.488-0500` to a Date object? I see [Groovy String to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817862/groovy-string-to-date) but that doesn't work in pipeline (I'm aware not all Groovy does work in pipeline).

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261710/getting-current-timestamp-in-inline-pipeline-script-using-pipeline-plugin-of-hud/43389597

Comment: Thanks @SivaKaruppiah, but that didn't have the answer.

Comment: where do you get this value "2019-11-05T08:43:43.488-0500" ?

Comment: You should consider the newer LocalDateTime instead of Date. Less hassle than Date in Jenkins pipelines. LocalDateTime.parse(...) will convert your string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to parse `String` to `Date` object in a Jenkins Pipipeline. And this is actually what the `Date.parse(format,date)` does under the hood - https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_12/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyStaticMethods.java#L186

You will need, however, approve using `DateFormat.parse(date)` method when you run it for the first time in the Jenkins Pipeline.

```
Scripts not permitted to use method java.text.DateFormat parse java.lang.String. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.text.DateFormat parse java.lang.String
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:175)
```

When you approve it, the following code should work for you:

```groovy
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def date = "2019-11-05T08:43:43.488-0500"
                    def format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

                    def parsed = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date)

                    echo "date = ${parsed}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Running on Jenkins in /home/wololock/.jenkins/workspace/pipeline-sandbox
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
date = Tue Nov 05 14:43:43 CET 2019
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```