# Fail a Jenkins build from groovy script

Tags: jenkins

I have a groovy script that goes and promotes code. Long story short, I know at a point of time within that script if it was successful or not.  I would like to fail the build if not successful.  Is there a way in groovy to fail the build?

Example:

in the "execute Groovy script" plugin.  you can write code.

`(insert API call to promote code) 
 if(checkPromote()){
     //fail build here
 }`

where 'checkPromote' returns a true or false value depending on the status of the promote.

Comment: return non-zero exitcode from your script. Should fail your build

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  `return -1`  that did not work.

Comment: I also tried to `return false`.

Comment: Than it might help if you provide a snippet of the buildfile and a description of the setup

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: What type of build? Looks like build-flow or freestyle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141676/discussion-between-eddie-and-rik).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The most elegant way to abort a programm in my opinion is an assertion.

`assert condition : "Build fails because..."`

Answer (score 25):

The declarative pipeline dsl has an error step:

```
error('Failing build because...')
```

See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps and search the page for "Error signal".

this would also do it:

```
sh "exit 1"
```

Comment: This isn't a pipeline job. This is a freestyle project

Comment: @Eddie are you sure? I don't think freestyle projects have groovy scripts.

Comment: @SINGULARITY they do, yes

Answer (score 8):

From this page, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin

```
import hudson.AbortException
//other code
throw new AbortException("Error message .")
```

Comment: Have you tried this? You'd seen the following error `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new hudson.AbortException`.

Comment: @acm Yes it works, although you have to approve the constructor for AbortException first, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412951/7509826

Comment: Nicely this doesn't include an unnecessary stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

There are different "groovy script"s in the Jenkins world. For every of them the solution is different.

1. "Execute Groovy script" plugin (a plain Groovy script which runs on a node)

   ```
    System.exit(1)
    // NOTE: Don't use it in System Groovy Script, Groovy Postbuild, Scriptler or Pipeline
    // because it runs on master and terminates the Jenkins server process!
   ```
2. System Groovy Script / Groovy Postbuild / Scriptler (runs on master):

   ```
    import hudson.model.*;
    def currentBuild = Thread.currentThread().executable
    currentBuild.result = Result.FAILURE
   ```

   This works only for "System Groovy Script"

   ```
    return 1
   ```
3. Pipeline:

   ```
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'// one way
    error("Error Message") // another way
   ```

There are of course more artificial methods like throwing an exception, execution of a faulty command, calling of unexisting function or a function with wrong arguments etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use something as simple as `throw new Exception("Error Message")` so maybe you can have try with:

```
    if(checkPromote()){
         throw new Exception("Error Message")
     }
```

Hope this also works for you

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
```