# How to translate groovy map to json

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the below code in Jenkins pipeline:

```
stage ("distribution"){
            steps{
                script{
                    def rules = [
                            service_name: "core", 
                            site_name: "*", 
                            city_name: "*", 
                            country_codes: ["*"]
                ]
                    amd_distribution_distribute_bundle distribution_rules: rules
                    }
                }
            }
```

As you can see, it's a map parameter. How can I convert it to the JSON file using Groovy code? At the end it should look like:

```
{
  "distribution_rules": [
    {
      "service_name": "core*",
      "site_name": "*",
      "city_name": "*",
      "country_codes": ["*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the below command but it didn't help:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def call(Map parameters)
{
    def DISTRIBUTION_RULES = parameters.distribution_rules
    def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    json rootKey: "${DISTRIBUTION_RULES}"
    writeFile file: 'rootKey', text: JsonOutput.toJson(json)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707265/create-json-strings-from-groovy-variables-in-jenkins-pipeline/44718808#44718808

Comment: Didn't realize what exactly I should write in the groovy file per the attachment

Comment: `def json = JsonOutput.toJson([ distribution_rules: rules ] )`,  then write `json` to file

Comment: This code is for the pipeline or groovy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need to mix `JsonBuilder` and `JsonOutput` in your `amd_distribution_distribute_bundle.groovy` file. The `JsonOutput.toJson(map)` method takes a regular `Map` and translates it to the JSON object equivalent. By default it creates a flat single line file. If you expect to get so-called pretty print, you need to use combination of `JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(map))`.

### Flat print

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def call(Map parameters) {
    def DISTRIBUTION_RULES = parameters.distribution_rules

    writeFile file: 'rootKey', text: JsonOutput.toJson([distribution_rules: [DISTRIBUTION_RULES]])
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat rootKey
{"distribution_rules":[{"service_name":"core","site_name":"*","city_name":"*","country_codes":["*"]}]}%
```

### Pretty print

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def call(Map parameters) {
    def DISTRIBUTION_RULES = parameters.distribution_rules

    writeFile file: 'rootKey', text: JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson([distribution_rules: [DISTRIBUTION_RULES]]))
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat rootKey
{
    "distribution_rules": [
        {
            "service_name": "core",
            "site_name": "*",
            "city_name": "*",
            "country_codes": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}%
```

Comment: just correct the syntax to: JsonOutput.toJson([ distribution_rules: rules ] )