# How to create json file with parameter varible in jenkins?

Tags: json, bash, jenkins

I am creating json file using echo statement ,it works fine as long as static string.

```
echo '
{
    "common": {
        "baseUri": "https://mycompany.com",
        "ipPrefix": "192.23.4.",
     }
}' > test.json
```

But when I need to interpolate string inside echo command it is not working.

```
 echo '
    {
        "common": {
            "baseUri": "$company_name",
            "ipPrefix": "192.23.4.",
         }
    }' > test.json
```

How to create json file in jenkins with parameter values substituted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create JSON strings from Groovy variables in Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707265/create-json-strings-from-groovy-variables-in-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: Regarding bash only, without considering jenkins/groovy : you are using single quotes, so no parameter expansion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-should-i-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the quotes as suggested in the comments.

Script below should work for you:

```sh
company_name="https://mycompany.com"
echo '{
     "common": {
          "baseUri": "'$company_name'",
          "ipPrefix": "192.23.4."
     }
}' > test.json
```

Output:

```sh
{
     "common": {
          "baseUri": "https://mycompany.com",
          "ipPrefix": "192.23.4."
     }
}
```

The value of any variable **can’t** be read by single quote `'`, since it only represents the *literal* value of all characters within it.
To get the value of `company_name` we need to end the single quotes, then add the variable and start single quotes again.

[Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
[Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting)

Answer (score 0):

With [pipeline utility steps plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writejson-write-json-to-a-file-in-the-workspace), you can write any groovy map straight to a JSON file:

```
def company_name = "http://mycompany.com/"
def map = [ 
    "common" : [ 
        "baseUri": company_name,
        "ipPrefix": "192.23.4."
    ]
]

writeJSON json: map, file: test.json
```