# Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.JsonBuilder

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am facing this error `Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.JsonBuilder` while building a jenkins pipeline. However the same code is working in `jenkins scriptler`. Should I do any changes on this code to write a Json file through jenkins pipeline

```
def vars = ["a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3,"d": 4,]
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def final_out = json "sample": vars
json "file": final_out
def file = new File("/tmp/sample.json")                                   
file.write(groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString()))
```

Sample output looks like:

```
{
    "file": {
        "sample": {
             "a": 1,
             "b": 2,
             "c": 3,
             "d": 4
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a native jenkins step writejson - use it instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707265/create-json-strings-from-groovy-variables-in-jenkins-pipeline/44718808#44718808

Comment: @daggett, i tried with the native jenkins writejson method, but I got this error ```groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.writeJson() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap)```

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writejson-write-json-to-a-file-in-the-workspace

Comment: it should be writeJSON

Comment: i think it was my mistake, i had incorrect map value. it worked once i resolved it. thank you