# Jenkins pipeline: Convert array to Set

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Within a `Jenkinsfile` in a multi-branch pipeline I'm trying to convert an array to a set to get unique elements but I always get

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException
```

with nothing present in the script approval page (/scriptApproval). I've tried:

```
def set = myArray.toSet()
def set = new HashSet(myArray)
```

but both give the `RejectedAccessException`. How can I accomplish finding unique elements in an array in Jenkins pipeline code?

Comment: How myArray is initialized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins CI Pipeline Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276341/jenkins-ci-pipeline-scripts-not-permitted-to-use-method-groovy-lang-groovyobject)