# Groovy get the filename with a specific ending only knowing the path

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm using groovy in my Jenkinsfiles. The gradle-build creates a jar looking like this: `appName-1.0.0-ua67435.jar` and is copied to `/opt/appName`

In the Jenkinsfile (Groovy) I now like to get this part of the string `1.0.0-ua67435` in a variable. I hope this regex should do the job: `-(.*?).jar$`

I know where my file is, but I don't know its name. Its the only `.jar` in the `/opt/appName/`-folder.

**How can I get the substring of my filename when I only know its place and name-pattern?**

Comment: You mean you want to get the string `appName-1.0.0-ua67435.jar` from the string `/opt/appName/appName-1.0.0-ua67435.jar`?

Comment: Yes while not knowing the exact name of `appName-****************.jar`. I'd prefer unknown part but only.

Comment: You can check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
new File("/opt/appName/").eachFileMatch(FileType.FILES, ~/^.*-.*?.jar$/, { println it.name })
```

It uses [eachFileMatch](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.7/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFileMatch(groovy.io.FileType,%20java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) to match the name with specific pattern, you can see more examples from the doc link.

---

Using the full qualified name  like this, if import is not allowed.

`...eachFileMatch(groovy.io.FileType.FILES,...`

Comment: How can i get that name in a variable?

Comment: @SWiggels `it.name` is the name you want.

Comment: I got import problems with FileType.FILES. It seems jenkins doesn't even like the import.

Comment: `import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES 
new File("$destDir").eachFileMatch(FileType.FILES, ~/^.*-.*?.jar$/, { println it.name })` results in 
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: FileType for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: Now i got the same error as for Wiktors idea. ?org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod ' and yes I approved it in the script-security of jenkins.

Comment: Ok i got the solution. Many thanks also to @Wiktor! The problem was that when running the script it asked for approval. After it said it has no rights i had to approve another time for other methods. I had to do this 3 times in a row. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
def names = []
new File("/opt/appName/").eachFileMatch groovy.io.FileType.FILES, ~/(?<=appName-).*(?=[.]jar$)/, { names << it.name }
```

The `(?<=appName-).*(?=[.]jar$)` regex will fetch just the variable part between `appName-` and `.jar` at the end of string. If you add `^` before `appName`, it will be matched only when at the start of the file name.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cc6cZe/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=appName-)` - make sure there is `appName` immediately to the left of the current location
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?=[.]jar$)` - make sure there is `.jar` substring followed with an end of string position immediately to the right of the current position.

More details about [`eachFileMatch` here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.7/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFileMatch(groovy.io.FileType,%20java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).

Comment: Jenkins does not allow static imports. Additionally `baseDir` is not known.

Comment: @SWiggels This is an example snippet from the docs. I just changed the regex there. The `baseDir` should be initialized with `"/opt/appName/"`, sure.

Comment: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod` is what I get from running it.

Comment: Try it the way aristotll suggests.

Comment: aristotlls version needs the import as well. Hence it doens't work either. :(

Comment: There is one question on SO suggesting: *Navigate to `jenkins` > `Manage jenkins` > `In-process Script Approval`. There was a pending command, which I had to approve.*. [There are other hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276341/jenkins-ci-pipeline-scripts-not-permitted-to-use-method-groovy-lang-groovyobject).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already approved it. If you do not approve it it says that your method is not allowed in scripts. After accepting I got the static import is generally not allowed...

Answer (score 0):

You can `FileNameFinder` class to find it easily:

```
println new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(folderPath, '**/appName*.jar').collect{ it.substring(it.lastIndexOf('/')+1, it.size())}
```

Comment: Using `FileNameFinder` in pipelines is dangerous if you are using slaves. Everything with files gets executed on the master only. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/yBiYbwWjg-I