# Groovy convert String to Long

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm coding a jenkins pipeline and I need to convert a String parameter in a Long value.

I have used Long.valueOf, Long.parseLong. I get this error message :

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.parseLong() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [8899986991733205013]

or this :

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.valueOf() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [8899986991733205013]

my code :

```
    def min = Long.valueOf(params.paymentid) + Integer.valueOf(params.begin)
    def max = Long.valueOf(params.paymentid) + Integer.valueOf(params.end)
```

Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: Long.parseLong(String ) expects a string argument. What is the type of params.begin, params.end and params.paymentid -- all String ??

Comment: You have `Integer` instead of `Long` in your sample code, but in your question you refer to "Long.valueOf" and "Long.parseLong"...

Comment: Yes i tried different things and I pasted one of my try, but Long.valuOf tells me this : org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.lang.Long valueOf java.lang.String

Comment: @JasonM1 param.begin, end and paymentid are all String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this solution in admin console :

```
print(params.paymendid.toLong())
```

it worked. On my pipeline it didn't work, i got this error :

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>   Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods toLong
>   java.lang.String

but this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412951/8357778 works.

I should disable sandbox.

Answer (score 15):

you should use the Long class:

```
def min = Long.valueOf('1')
```

Comment: Sorry my paste is bad, but I tried it and the error was : 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.lang.Long valueOf java.lang.String

Answer (score 9):

The following conversion will also work.

```
Long paymentId = params.paymentid as Long
println paymentId
```

You can put this block inside **try..catch** block to handle any **type casting exception** if the string is invalid.