# emailext - should send email only if html report is available else should not email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My goal is  -- Very often **emailext** sends emails with error messages like

> ERROR: File 'path/to/index.html' does not exist

My code looks like this

```
emailext(to: 'jane.doe@foo.com',
        subject: 'Build report',
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        body: '${FILE,path="path/to/index.html"}',
)
```

This error message is correct. There was no html report produced. But I want this email to be sent out only if there is an html report and to **not** send error messages when there is no html report.

Any ideas on how to achieve this behavior?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groovy's `File.exists` method to check if given file exists or not, and run the script accordingly.

```
def file = new File( 'path/to/index.html' )

// If it exists
if( file.exists() ) {
  emailext(to: 'jane.doe@foo.com',
        subject: 'Build report',
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        body: '${FILE,path="path/to/index.html"}',
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried it and I get `scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.io.File exists`

Comment: Try [Jenkins CI Pipeline Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412951/3358570)

Answer (score 0):

```
  post {
    always {
        echo 'I will always say Hello again!'
        
        emailext body: '${FILE,path="report/report.html"}',
            mimeType: 'text/html',
            to: "example@example.com",
            subject: "Daily Automation Report"
    }
}
```