# How do I import a class using GroovyScript and Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following in a groovy file...

```
// jenkins/Application.groovy
package jenkins

class Application{
    String name
    Application(name){
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

I am trying to import it and I have tried these but none seem to work. These are all in jenkins/Test.groovy

```
final GroovyScriptEngineImpl engine = (GroovyScriptEngineImpl) this.scriptingEngines.getEngineByName("groovy");
GroovyClassLoader classLoader = engine.getClassLoader();
classLoader.parseClass(new GroovyCodeSource("./jenkins/Application.groovy"))
engine.setClassLoader(classLoader)
```

This gives..

> Script1.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class Application

Then I tried...

```
// jenkins/Application.groovy
// Added
return { Application }
// jenkins/Test.groovy
app = load "./jenkins/Application.groovy"

def dna = new app.Application("blah")
```

and I get...

> Script1.groovy: 11: unable to resolve class app.Application

How do I import a call in a Jenkins GroovyScript?

**Update**

I changed my code to the following (and moved into a domain folder)...

```
app = load "./jenkins/domain/Application.groovy"
def dna = app.newInstance([name:"blah"] as Object[])
```

When I run I get...

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods newInstance java.lang.Class java.lang.Object[]

Comment: Is it a Jenkins pipeline? Or just groovy plugin in Jenkins?

Comment: it is a pipeline

Comment: It also does work fine if it is in the same file

Comment: why you are not using a standard way: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/  ?

Comment: related ideas: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: @daggett I am I have a pipeline and I call run pipeline... def pipeline = load "./jenkins/featurePipeline.groovy" || pipeline.runPipeline(...)

Answer (score 1):

**the idea**

you could return from loaded script - the class (not an instance)

then to create new instance you could call `class.newInstance( Object [] argList )`

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object[])

so, theoretically this should work:

**./jenkins/Application.groovy**

```
class Application{
    String name
    Application(name){
        this.name = name
    }
}

return Application.class
```

**pipeline:**

```
def app = load "./jenkins/Application.groovy"
def dna = app.newInstance( "blah" )
```

Comment: Thanks! any idea how I would use the type in a constructor? I know groovy is not typed but I was hoping I could use it

Comment: Getting [ERROR] Exception in pipeline: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.newInstance() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[103740]]
Possible solutions: newInstance(), newInstance(), newInstance([Ljava.lang.Object;), isInstance(java.lang.Object)

Comment: For your update there is a standard solution - administrator.

Comment: Not sure I follow does that mean an admin has to configure something because that probably won't happen

Comment: It's quite standard security issue. Just search over the Internet. Jenkins restricts calling some methods.
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276341/jenkins-ci-pipeline-scripts-not-permitted-to-use-method-groovy-lang-groovyobject