# Update app .properties file from jenkins groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, github, groovy, properties-file

I am developing an app which consumes credentials/secrets from Jenkins vault. I am getting it via withCredntials in the groovy script. After getting the credentials I need to update the same in my application properties file before the jar generation.

I have tried to achieve this by some of the tips from google search, but nothing worked. I have used push commands to get this done. Please help me to sort out this issue.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '<vault key>', 
usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
 // push logic 
}

First Approach: 
touch myapp.properties 
git config --global db.cred= "${USER} 
git add myapp.properties 
git commit -m 'file added' 
git push central mybranch 

o/p - no results, no errors 

Second approach: 
def newFile=new File("myapp.properties") 
newFile.write("db.creds..") 
git add myapp.properties 
git commit -m 'file added' 
git push central mybranch 

o/p: Error - Scripts not permitted to use java.io.File.java.lang.String
```

Jenkins build is not triggering after the push statement

Comment: Please share your code and the error/problem. Otherwise it's not clear what issue do you have

Comment: First Approach: 
touch myapp.properties
git config --global db.cred= "${USER}
git add myapp.properties
git commit -m 'file added'
git push central mybranch

o/p - no results, no errors

Second approach:
def newFile=new File("myapp.properties")
newFile.write("db.creds..");
git add myapp.properties
git commit -m 'file added'
git push central mybranch

o/p: Error -  Scripts not permitted to use java.io.File.java.lang.String

Comment: Please put all this into your question. It's impossible to read code in comments )

Comment: Done. please check

Comment: Your question already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276341/jenkins-ci-pipeline-scripts-not-permitted-to-use-method-groovy-lang-groovyobject