# Counting falling tests from JUnitArchiver

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using groovy in jenkins pipeline scripts. How i can take the results of falling unit tests from junit report file? Now i'm trying to get them by code:

```
import hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction
import hudson.model.*
import java.*
import java.lang.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
```

...some code ...

```
dir (workspace){                 
    step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', keepLongStdio: true, testResults: "artifacts/*/*.xml"])
    result_junit = count_fail_unit_tests()
    echo "UNIT TESTS FAIL COUNT: ${result_junit}"                     
    if (result_junit != 0){
            currentBuild.displayName = "UNIT TESTS FAIL"
        }
    throw new Exception("warning_exception")
    }
archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: "log/*", caseSensitive: false
}


@NonCPS
def count_fail_unit_tests() {           
    def count_fail_tests = manager.build.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).getFailCount()
    return count_fail_tests
}
```

and got an error

> ERROR: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager
>   for class: Script4

Earlier i got the count of errors by code:

```
dir (workspace){
    result_junit = junit keepLongStdio: true, testResults: "artifacts/*/*.xml"
    echo "UNIT TESTS FAIL COUNT: ${result_junit}"                     
    if (result_junit != 0){
            currentBuild.displayName = "UNIT TESTS FAIL"
        }
    throw new Exception("warning_exception")
    }
archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: "log/*", caseSensitive: false
}
```

and it was working, but it had bug: 
if use `junit keepLongStdio: true, testResults: "artifacts/*/*.xml"` and report .xml file has incorrect structure, building not failing and stay in status "SUCCESS".
With using `step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', keepLongStdio: true, testResults: "artifacts/*/*.xml"])` it fails, thats why i want to use this metod.
If i try

```
some_return = step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', keepLongStdio: true, testResults: "artifacts/*/*.xml"]) 
echo "${some_return}"
```

get

> null

Is there some metods for `junit keepLongStdio: true, testResults: "artifacts/*/*.xml"` to fail build, if xml junit report is incorrect?
Or how i can take counts from

```
step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', keepLongStdio: true, testResults: "artifacts/*/*.xml"])
```

Comment: Try to use `currentBuild.rawBuild` in place of `manager.build`.

Comment: try this 
and got another error:
[ERROR: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction getFailCount]

Comment: @zett42
Thanks for answer, i tried this 
`currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).getFailCount();`
and got another error:
[ERROR: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction getFailCount]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38276341/7571258